# How to avoid installing jq/docker into container running inside of WITH DOCKER block?

Tags: earthly

I build JVM-based project and would like to have an Earthly target with integration steps similar to [this one](https://github.com/earthly/earthly/blob/v0.7.2/examples/integration-test/Earthfile#L39) using `WITH DOCKER ... END` syntax.
`WITH DOCKER` command is needed to have a real database instance available in the context of integration tests execution.

Since I work on a JVM project, my base image for executing any commands related to build system is: `FROM bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine:17`. The thing which I find suboptimal is that for any command running inside of `WITH DOCKER ... END` block Earthly check for presence of `jq` and `docker`/`docker-compose` projects. Each time I execute integration tests on CI node, jq and docker get installed, while they are completely useless in my `WITH DOCKER` usage scenario.

Is there a way to disable their installation? Right now, as a workaround, I consider adding jq and docker to my base `bellsoft/liberica-openjdk-alpine:17` builder-image to make docker/jq installation `*cached*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alex Couture-Beil](https://github.com/alexcb) recently provided good answer to this question on [Earthly Slack](https://earthly.dev/slack)

I think that's the best way to avoid installing dependencies on each build, just use the [recommended `earthly/dind:alpine`](https://docs.earthly.dev/docs/guides/docker-in-earthly#performance) for `WITH DOCKER` commands, it will only be downloaded once and run tests with `docker run` instead of `RUN`. Here is how I changed my pipeline now:

```
test:
    FROM earthly/dind:alpine # <-- recommended image for 'WITH DOCKER' commands, docker and jq are already there
    COPY docker-compose.yaml ./
    WITH DOCKER --compose docker-compose.yaml --service=mongo --load build-image=+compile
        RUN docker run --name tests-container --network=host build-image \
        ./gradlew test \
        && \
        docker cp tests-container:/build/ build/ # <-- get test execution results
    END
    SAVE ARTIFACT build/test-results
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `INSTALL_DIND` UDC for this. The best practices guide touches on this under the [`# Better` example](https://docs.earthly.dev/best-practices#use-earthly-dind).

This allows you to use a custom base image and also install dependencies on top, and then do any cache-busting operations (like COPY) after.

```
FROM some-other-image:latest
DO github.com/earthly/lib+INSTALL_DIND
COPY ...
WITH DOCKER ...
   RUN ...
END
```

Another good option is to use the `earthly/dind` image and instead put the JDK-related things in another container that you then `--load` and run via `docker run` within the `WITH DOCKER`. However it sounds like this might not be a viable option for you.

Comment: Thank you! I would still prefer to have an option to skip installing these dependencies (skipping this would make my jvm-"builder" image smaller, which in turn would make cloud CIs to download less on each build). Yeah, I will go the first option and install docker/jq into my jvm-builder, because it's easier than installing JDK distribution I need in top of `earthly/dind`